# Git upstream only specific directory from a repo in Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I have a repo that looks like this

```
MAIN
|
|--AndroidApp
|--ServerApp
```

Now I wish to deploy the serverApp in Heroku. Any ideas if it is possible and how to do it ?

Currently I tried the

```
heroku git:remote -a afternoon-mesa-61125
```

but this produced

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to afternoon-mesa-61125.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-mesa-61125.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-mesa-61125.git'
```

Help please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out what the problem was I ran the

```
gunicorn server.wsgi:application
```

command which outputted a more descriptive error.

I hope this helps someone

P.S. My error was that I

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")
```

in stead of:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
```